# How to debug a Linux kernel module at source level?

Tags: linux, user-interface, debugging, module

I'm developing a Linux Device Driver for Zynq7000 which needs to plug into the RapidIO framework under buildroot environment. My debugging tools are printk+dmesg and the site https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source: they are too poor and time consuming tools! So in the development environment (Virtual Box on x86 PC running Xubuntu 20.04) I would like to use a symbolic debugger with a graphical front-end: reading here and there I understand that I have to use kgdb and eclipse.
I have some questions:

0. are kgdb + eclipse the better choice? Does the effort of setting up an open source debug environment pays in the end or is it better to use an emulator like Lauterbach?
1. must the communication channel between the target and the debugging machine be a serial one? I would like to use the ethernet: if it is possible how to configure it?
2. does the debugged kernel module have to be compiled together with the kernel or can it be compiled separately from the kernel and then loaded via insmod? If yes, how do you do it?
3. On the web, what are the most significant resources to read in order to correctly set up the debugging environment that is the subject of this post?

.... but why is it so difficult?

Thanks in advance!